# Uncaught typeerror cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I am quite new in JS. I wrote two small code sections for inserting HTML on homepage/frontpage. Both work properly only when I execute it in the chrome console (ctrl + shift + J), but when I paste it directly into a theme/header/footer, both scripts gave almost the same error indicated in the topic title. I tried adding the code at the beginning of the head tag **/** before the closing body tag with the defer attribute **/** wrapped it window.onload = function(){/*code*/}; but nothing helped :(
The script itself/site is here https://shashlichok.online/moy.js (added before /body at this moment).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering when pasting the code directly into a theme/header/footer is likely due to the code being executed before the element exists in the DOM. When you run the code in the Chrome console, the DOM is already loaded, so it works fine there.

Try wrapping your code inside the event listener for the "DOMContentLoaded" event, it will wait for the DOM to be fully loaded before executing.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
//write your code here
})
```

Comment: I understand. The error(s) is/are still the same. 
moy.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')
    at moy.js:13:17
moy.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'before')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (moy.js:7:11)
I also noticed that variables are declared, but not defined (values are not assigned).